# Another "this" query, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, this

The following code is used as in inheritance method in JavaScript but I am having trouble following the code, specifically the context of "this" so I've added questions as code comments. Thanks in advance for the enlightenment.

```
var Class = function(){
    var klass = function(){
        //Is "this" referring to the Class class or Klass class?
        //Why is "this" being applied to "this.init"? Isn't this default behavior? 
        //Are they both the same "this"?
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    klass.prototype.init = function(){};
    return klass;
};

var Person = new Class;

Person.prototype.init = function(){
// Called on Person instantiation
};

// Usage:
var person = new Person;
```

Apologies if I'm misinterpreting this whole thing.

Comment: You should read what `apply` does. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: MDN has a pretty extensive explanation of how `this` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` always refers to the caller of a function. If you call a function like `person.init()` then `this` refers to the `Person` instance. If you call a function without specifying the `this` like `alert()` then it will refer to the `window`.

> Is "this" referring to the Class class or Klass class?

Neither, exactly. In the end, it refers to the new `Person` instance that you're creating.

> Why is "this" being applied to "this.init"? Isn't this default behavior?

If you don't prefix with `this` then it's going to assume you're talking about some other variable/function, typically a global unless you have a closure.

> Are they both the same "this"?

If by both you mean `Class` and `klass` then no. As the first question states: `this` is determined by the caller or `new`.

One thing that may be confusing is the use of `apply`. All that `apply` does it allows you to set the caller of a function before calling it and pass any arguments as an array. The reason they do this is to allow the user to pass their own arguments. For example, say we have the following two init functions:

```
Person.prototype.init = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

Person2.prototype.init = function(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
};
```

`klass` needs to have some way of passing in those arguments to the init functions. It does this using `apply`. So the following are functionally equivalent:

```
var klass = function(a, b) {
    this.init(a, b);
};

// This one can take ANY number of arguments, not just two
var klass = function() {
    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

This works because `arguments` is essentially an array of the passed arguments.

Comment: I like your answer, apart from the first sentence. The caller of a function is usually another function. For example: `function foo() { bar(); }`. Here, `foo` would be the caller of `bar`, but `this` won't refer to `foo`.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand why this.init need itself to be applied to its own function regardless of what this actually is.

Comment: @Nate I've expanded my answer to explain why they do that. Felix Kling: Good point, I've updated the first sentence to be a bit more accurate.

Comment: @Mike C Thank you for your answer, and specifically about the use of apply as a mechanism to pass in arguments. This has helped me to understand a lot better the reasoning behind this sort of code. Cheers.

Comment: You may want to add mention though that `this` will be equal to `undefined` if `"use strict";` is in effect on the function or its surrounding scope.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good questions and answers on SO concerning Javascript scope, but the key concept to understand is.. the value of the variable this is established by the caller.  The answer to your question - "this" could point to almost anything.